# Deserialize JSON string into Dynamic List in VB.net

Tags: json, vb.net, asp.net-web-api, deserialization

I've got the following JSON string which I have retrieved from a webapi:

```
[{"WorkOrderID":2,"WorkOrderNumber":1},{"WorkOrderID":3,"WorkOrderNumber":3}]
```

Now I want to know if there is a way I can deserialize this into a list of type dynamic in VB.NET?

The JSON string could be coming in any format (therefore I cannot deserialize it to a standard class type) and I just need to deserialize it into a list so it can be used a datasource for a grid.

Is this achievable.

Comment: The [JSON.Net project](http://json.codeplex.com/) on Codeplex might help get you started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For VB.Net:

```
Dim x As Object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(of Object)(json)
```